# How to explode two array and use in same for each loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have two comma separated value like bellow how can I also loop through 2nd array and use them as link text.

Values=

```
$link_array ="urllink1,urllink2,urllink3";
$text_array ="text1,text2,text3";
```

explode them to separate array's value

```
$links = explode(",",$link_array);
$texts = explode(",",$text_array);
```

**Loop through each value**

```
foreach($links as $url){
    echo'<a href="'.$url.'">Link text</a>';
}
```

How can I i use 2nd array as text link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the key as index.

```
foreach($links as $index => $url)
    echo '<a href="', $url, '">', $texts[$index], '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to work with $urls and $texts array at the same time, so try this php code:

```
<?php
    array_map(function($p1, $p2){
        echo "<a href='$p1'>$p2</a><br>";
    }, $links, $texts);
?>
```

Comment: My data is comma separated value

Comment: The intention of `array_map()` is to return an array. So `echo join('', array_map(fn($p1, $p2) => "<a href='$p1'>$p2</a><br>", $links, $texts));` would be the expected.